# Find the mean of the value of the coins.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

A bag contains a large number of coins. Half of them are \$1 coins, one-third are  \$2 coins, and the remainder are $5 coins.

1. Find the mean of the value of the coins.
2. If a random sample of 2 coins is chosen from the bag, list all possible samples that can be drawn.
3. Let X be the total value of the 2 coins drawn. Find the probability distribution of X.
4. Find the probability that X < $12.

** Answers **

P($1) = 1/2

P($2) = 1/3

P($5) = 1/6  :  Given

Random variable = X

X | 1 | 2 | 5 |

P | $\frac{1}{2}$ | $\frac{1}{3}$ | $\frac{1}{6}$ |

1. mean = 1 . $\frac{1}{2}$ + 2 . $\frac{1}{3}$ + 5 . $\frac{1}{6}$ = 2
2. {1,2} , {1,5} , {2,5} , {1,1} , {2,2} , {5,5}

Are those answers correct?

How to solve the 3rd and 4th questions?

Comment: Your third value for $X$ in your pdf table (X, P) should be $5$, not $3$; with corresponding change to your answer to problem 1.

Comment: (2) does not look correct:  you might draw two $\$1$ coins

Comment: For problem 2, you have neglected the possibility of drawing the same value twice.

Comment: For (4), is it even possible to have $X\ge \$12$ with two coins?

Comment: @paw88789 noted, thanks.

Comment: @Henry noted, thanks.

Comment: @paw88789 X≥$12 not possible.

Comment: 3) to work out the probability distribution, you need to work out the probability of getting each possible sum, e.g 3 can be arrived at by 1 then 2 or 2 then 1 - prob = (1/2) (1/3) + (1/3)(1/2) = 1/3 - but bear in mind for example that there is only one way of getting 2$, which is 1 then 1.

Comment: @Caedmon if $X\ge \$12$ is impossible then $\mathbb P( X\lt \$12)=1$ as you have spotted in your answer

Comment: @Henry Oops, I misunderstood what you wrote. Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

Answer 1 is not correct. You're last value in your addition should be $5*\frac{1}{6}$ giving a total mean of $\$2$. Also for answer two, all the possibilities are:
{1,1}, {1,2}, {1,5}, {2,2}, {2,5}, {5,5}

For question 3, the probability will have a mean of $\$4$. However, do you know the size of the sample? As in do you know how many samples of $2$ coins are you drawing? That would allow us to calculate the standard deviation and even if the distribution was approximately normal. We can also determine that all values of X will fall into columns of values $\$2$, $\$3$, $\$4$, $\$6$, $\$7$ and $\$10$, and you can calculate the probability of each of those columns. We have all possible sample spaces, but we need to adjust slightly. We can draw: {1,2} and {2,1}, which give the same total, but we have 2 ways to achieve it. Let's list all the possible values of $X$, all of the possible ways to get them, and then the probabilities. Note we can add these probabilities because the events are mutually exclusive.

$\$2$: {1,1} : $\frac{1}{2} * \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4}$

$\$3$: {1,2} {2,1} : $\frac{1}{2} * \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3} * \frac{1}{2} = \frac{2}{6} = \frac{1}{3}$

$\$4$: {2,2} : $\frac{1}{3} * \frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{9}$

$\$6$: {1,5} {5,1} : $\frac{1}{2} * \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{6} * \frac{1}{2} = \frac{2}{12} = \frac{1}{6}$

$\$7$: {2,5} {5,2} : $\frac{1}{3} * \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{6} * \frac{1}{3} = \frac{2}{18} = \frac{1}{9}$

$\$10$: {5,5} : $\frac{1}{6} * \frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{36}$

Add these probabilities all up and they equal a probability of 1. You can draw a small bar chart or histogram with the $ values on the X-axis and the probabilities on the Y-axis. However, be very careful, this graph would only be true for many many many samples.

Lastly for question 4, looking at all the possibilities for 2 coins, we can see that there is no possibility for $X$ to be greater than or equal to 12, so then $P(X < \$12) = 1$, again, $\$10$ is the max we can draw.